# MIDI instruments sound different when exported to .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, javax.sound.midi, midi-instrument

I have made a java program that synthesises sounds using the MIDI package in the java sound API, however, when I export it to a .jar file, the sound played is quite different to what it is when I run it in eclipse. Does anyone know why it is doing this or how to fix this problem?

A list of the instruments can be found here: http://www.hittrax.com.au/images/artists/gmgs.pdf

Below is a section of my code

```
try {
        Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synth.open();
        MidiChannel[] channels = synth.getChannels();
        channels[0].programChange(123); // Set the instrument to be played (integer between 0 and 127)

        channels[0].noteOn(60, 80); // Play Middle C
        Thread.sleep(duration);
        channels[0].noteOff(60);
        Thread.sleep(500);

        synth.close();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The image below shows the audio when I record it, the first one is what the sound should be as on eclipse, the second one is what the sound is when exported to a .jar

[image: Sound Waves]

Comment: Is the `channels[0]` vs. `channels[channel]` a copy paste typo?

Comment: yes it is, good pick up, ill fix that up thanks

Comment: Just a guess but maybe eclipse is defining a "javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer" property which causes getSynthesizer() to return a different default synth?

Comment: @davidgiga1993 I think you are right, I tried printing the array, synth.getAvailableInstruments() and it came up as different (yet similar) instrument names for eclipse and the .jar, annoying because the eclipse sounds are so much better

Answer (score 1):

As you just found out Java returns different default synthesizer when running the jar file outside of eclipse.

This might be caused by the `javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer` property or a `sound.properties` file in the classpath.

As a workaround you could print the property value when running the application inside of eclipse and set it manually so the jar file uses the same synthesizer.

**Edit:**

If you want to use `com.sun.media.sound.MixerSynth` as default create the property

```
javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer=com.sun.media.sound.MixerSynth
```

Example:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer", "com.sun.media.sound.MixerSynth");
Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
....
```

More information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiSystem.html)

Comment: The synthesizer in eclipse is the 'com.sun.media.sound.MixerSynth' and in Java it is 'com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer' how can I change this?